# Android: Facebook API to post

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Faccebook android API (com.facebook.android) to post the messages on facebook.

  `Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(Constants.APP_ID);
  AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("message", "this is a test post");// the message to post to the wall
  mFacebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, new SampleDialogListener());`

Everything is working fine. I'm able to login and post the message, but after login, it is displaying a intermediate dialog, "Publish story" with a text box with my post msg, "this is a test post" that is editable by the user, but i want to post the messages immediately after login without having this intermediate post screen.

Can anybody help me how to achieve this.

Thanks,
nehatha

Comment: @BilltheLizard my answer is always helping to all and the code is so big so that i was not posted here and i will not change my blog post url in future so deletion of my answer is totally unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(3);
    bundle.putString("message", "Hello!");
    mFacebook.request("me/feed", bundle, "POST");
```